# Static method call from Eclipse Plugin: InjectionException

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, static-methods, noclassdeffounderror

I have 2 plugin projects - generator.ui and generator.core.
The generator.ui depends on generator.core plugin for processes and data manipulation. However wherever there is an API call on generator.core (through static method invocation), I get an exception mentioned below:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/upb/crc901/serge/generator/Generator
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:850).........
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.upb.crc901.serge.generator.Generator cannot be found by de.upb.crc901.serge.ui_1.0.0.qualifier
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Now this NoClassDefFoundError always comes for the class which contains static method for object creation as the design pattern followed is "Singleton".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code, From the UI plugin; the configuration hub class:

```java
public class ConfigurationHub implements IConfigurationHub {
private IGenerator generator;
private static IConfigurationHub configurationHub;

/*
 * Constructor private to make Singleton
 */
private ConfigurationHub() {
    generator = GeneratorFactory.createGenerator(Generator.class);
}

public static synchronized IConfigurationHub getInstance() {
    if(null == configurationHub) {
        configurationHub = new ConfigurationHub();
    }
    return configurationHub;
}
}
```

The GeneratorFactory class is in Generator plugin:

```java
public class GeneratorFactory {
private GeneratorFactory() {}
public static <T extends IGenerator> T createGenerator(Class<T> type) {
    try {
        return (T) type.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Regards,
Sid

Comment: The exception says the bundle class loader cannot find the class `de.upb.crc901.serge.generator.Generator`, does this class exist in the `de.upb.crc901.serge.ui` plugin?

Comment: Yes, the class exists and also the related package is included in the Exported Package of the generator plugin. This problem only comes up if I call the static method. In case I remove the static method and replace it with non-static, the problem goes away.

Comment: Call the static method from where? I think we need to see some code.

Comment: I have added the codes above, do you think this is sufficient. Please let me know in case you need any other info.

Comment: Is the Generator plugin in the plugin dependencies for the UI plugin? It looks like it needs to be. How are these classes used in the command handler that is failing?

Comment: Yes it is.

The problem I think is the classloader is not able to load the Generator class in the DefaultClassLoader.class

Comment: The Eclipse bundle class loaders will only load classes from plugins in the dependencies list.

Comment: Here is my finding: In the org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.class , there is a method findRequiredSource(..) , this method is responsible for loading the classes from the dependent plugins. Here I can see the generator plugin, but it fails to load the class from that plugin.

Comment: I think I should be hanged for this :)  There were 2 issues related to this problem. First and foremost, I saw the classpath to output folder was missing, so I added a (.) in the manifest file.

Secondly, there was a problem in one of the jars on which the Generator was dependent. On resolving that, all my problems got resolved.

Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it :)